# Domain / DNS injection issue - scam links seemingly coming from my website

Tags: url, dns, session-hijacking

I recently looked into Google Search Console and it shows "Hacked: URL injection". There are several scam links that seemingly look like they are part of my website.

I tried removing all hosting data but they were still accessible. So I asked my hosting support to deal with this but after a week they claim there is nothing wrong and the links don't exist, but I can definitely see they are active.

I searched online, it might be DNS issue, but really not sure how to resolve this. I can move my hosting to a different company, but they are not able to tell me whether that will fix the issue.

these are the sample links, there are like 30 more..

http://isuzu-wizard.i.beam.frantisekzeman.com/post/resume-star-wars-episode-6

http://msd-box-wire.i.beam.frantisekzeman.com/post/resume-meaning-tagalog

http://cm-chain-hoi.i.beam.frantisekzeman.com/resume/best-volunteer-certificate-templates-download-certificate

Can someone advise how to get rid of these?